# How to fix serialPort.Write slowing program down

Tags: c#

In sending programs to CNC(Computer Numerical Control) machines my program can receive data at 4800 baud fine, but when I use `serialPort.Write` I have to put a wait function of some sort in or the machine errors out immediately.

Even when I use a wait as small or smaller than `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);` it causes the output to take at least 3 times as long as a commercial program does at 4800 baud.

This sleep code happens at each character, but 10ms should not be noticeable in the scheme of things at such a low baud rate. It works but it is slow, too slow, the machine might actually out run it.

I tried it at 9600 baud and it worked but at the same speed. I did an old school loop as a timer and it worked the same way.  My code is quite simple, there must be something I dont know or understand about writing to the serial port.

The machine will error out immediately if i try to use `serialPort.Writeline` or if I remove any one of the sleeps. If I take one of the the sleep commands out, the machine will error out immediately and then the output runs extremely fast to the monitor textbox, so I know its not that the code is slow, it has to be something to do with the write command?

Its like if you write one character too soon after the last the machine errors out but again other programs actually get 2400 baud thruput, so its me...My computer science degree is pre OOP(83) and my full time job has been working in a machine shop for the last 25 years so Im not up on this as I should be.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++)// step thru all lines of program
            {
                ln = sendtext.Lines[i];
                leng = ln.Length;

                for (int x = 0; x <= leng - 1; x++)
                //step thru all characters of line
                {
                    ch = Convert.ToString(ln[x]);
                    serialPort1.Write(ch);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                    //  await Task.Delay(1); // does not change preformance
                    //  Task.Delay(timingconst).Wait();//does not change
                    textBox4.AppendText(Convert.ToString(ch));
                }
                serialPort1.Write(Convert.ToString((char)13));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timingconst);
                textBox4.AppendText(Convert.ToString((char)13));
                serialPort1.Write(Convert.ToString((char)10));
                textBox4.AppendText(Convert.ToString((char)10));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timingconst);
             }
```

Comment: By the way, I am obviously only sending 1 character per call to write, if I try to send the while line, ln in this case the machine errors out immediately.

Comment: Have you tried sending a fixed number of characters before sleeping?  If the device has a FIFO, you need to avoid overflowing it, which you can do with bursts.  You should also look into the flow control options.

Comment: If I send more than 1 character before sleeping the machine errors out unless there is a sleep between. However the sleep I am using does not add up to anything like the time that is being consumed. Im going to try the below code tomorrow in hopes this method will work: . Handshaking is set to none on both and it will error out literally on the second character.                                             
                        byte[] result = uniencoding.GetBytes(ln);
                        serialPort1.BaseStream.WriteAsync(result,0,leng);
                        Task.Delay(20).Wait();